# sp_rename en SQL server dentro de un exec

Tags: sql-server, base-de-datos, stored-procedure, cursor

Quiero utilizar la funcion de sql server sp_rename, el problema es que la tengo que meter dentro de un exec, puesto que la base de datos sobre la que se ejecuta es dinámica y la tengo dentro de un cursor. El caso es que la siguiente sentencia funciona correctamente:

```
EXEC (@name+'..sp_rename "valores", "valores2"')
```

Siendo @name la variable del cursor que me indica la base de datos sobre la que aplica.

Pero si intento hacer esto

```
EXEC(   'select ''hola''; '
        +@name+'..sp_rename "valores", "valores2"
        ')
```

Necesito poner un select antes de la ejecución dle sp_rename pero no funciona.

Tiene que ser algo de la sintaxis, pero me estoy volviendo loco y no lo consigo.

Si alguien puede echarme una mano se lo agradecería.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día sobre tu inquietud puedes hacer los siguiente:

```
DECLARE @consultaDinamica varchar(50);

SET @consultaDinamica = 'SELECT GETDATE() AS fechActual;';

EXEC (@consultaDinamica+' EXEC sp_rename "valores", "valores2"');
```

Lo que sucede es que como estas usando un exec de igual forma cuando ejecutas tienes que add el exec interno junto a  tu instrucción y de esta manera brinda respuesta y hace la consulta... a modo de example add lo del getDate pero en tu caso seria colocar lo que deba ir en tu select según sea la lógica que requieras.

Espero te sea de utilidad, saludos.

Comment: Sí que me ha servido, muchas gracias!